# Display collection wchich data is not null from mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Hello i would like to display n countries with the oldest date in field independence but without null value.

I have something like this but i dont know how to exclude all null values.

```
db.countries.find({}, {
  "independence": 1,
  "_id": 0
}).sort({
  "independence": 1
}).limit(10);
```

this my collection

```
{
    "name" : "Example",
    "code" : "AXB",
    "independence" : null,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) to select documents where independence field is present:

```
db.countries.find({
  independence: {
    $exists: true
  }
}, {
  "independence": 1,
  "_id": 0
}).sort({
  "independence": 1
}).limit(10);
```

If independence field can exist with null value and you need to fetch documents where that field is a date then you can use [`$type`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/):

```
db.countries.find({
  independence: {
    $type: "date"
  }
})
```